# sh -c in background

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, sh

#### Original version:

<strike>How to run sudo sh -c "command" in back ground</strike>

In a terminal

sudo sh -c "command" & starts in background but as soon as I press enter, the process exits

```
[test@localhost app]$ sudo sh -c 'app start' &                        
[3] 31725 

[test@locahost app]$

[3]+  Stopped                 sudo sh -c 'app start'
```

#### Rewrite:

I want to run *`some long-running command`* in the background, as root. 
The “obvious” way to do this is

```
sudo some long-running command &
```

For unspecified reasons I also tried

```
sudo sh -c 'some long-running command' &
```

Both of these fail the same way: I get a shell prompt,
but then, as soon as I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I get an error message:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'some long-running command' &
 [3] 31725

$

[3]+ Stopped sudo sh -c 'some long-running command'
$
```

It’s been pointed out to me that, when I put the `sudo` command
into the background like this, it loses access to the standard input. 
Therefore, it cannot read the password, and it is stopped when it tries.

Another approach is to use the `-b` option to tell `sudo`
to put the *`long-running command`* into the background,
rather than putting `sudo` into the background:

```
sudo -b some long-running command
```

or

```
sudo -b sh -c 'some long-running command'
```

Oh!  I almost forgot to mention!  My requirements include

- Must be able to redirect the output of the *`long-running command`* to a file.
- Must be able to capture the exit status of the *`long-running command`*,
  presumably writing it to a file.
- Must be able to get the PID of the background process in some reliable way
  (without needing to `grep` through the output of `ps`).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all, the process doesn't exit; it stops.  There is a difference.
2. Secondly, it probably happens immediately;
   you just don't get notified until after you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Third, when you put a command into the background (with `&`),

   it puts the standard input into a special state
   so background processes can't read from the keyboard. 
   When you put `sudo` into the background, it can't read the password,
   and so it gets stopped.
4. Fix this by telling `sudo` to put the command into the background
   (rather than telling your login shell to put `sudo` into the background):

   ```
   sudo -b sh -c 'app start'
   ```
5. For a simple command like "app start", there's no obvious need for `sh -c`. 
   Try

   ```
   sudo -b 'app start'
   ```

P.S. This question really has nothing to do with `sh -c`. 
You would have the same issue with something like

```
sudo sleep 42 &
```

Comment: I just provided that as an example. My goal was to run a program in background and get the process id. The command would be somewhat like this sudo-b sh -c 'app start > out.txt ; echo $? > ret.txt' & , this should ask for the sudo password and return me the process id of the sudo process. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of approaches:

```
sudo sh -c '(some long-running command > out.txt; echo $? > ret.txt)& echo $!'
```

and

```
sudo -b sh -c 'echo $$ > pid.txt; some long-running command > out.txt; echo $? > ret.txt'
```

A slightly trickier approach:

```
sudo sleep 0
sudo sh -c 'echo $$ > pid.txt; some long-running command > out.txt; echo $? > ret.txt' &
```

where the `sudo sleep 0` asks for your password and caches your credentials,
so the next `sudo` command can proceed without asking for your password.

All of these give you the PID of the `sh -c` process
rather than the *`long-running command`* process.